# Ratio of two line segments in a special right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

So I had this question in my mind for a while.

[image]

At first, I tried using a bunch of theorems such as the Law of Sines, the Law of Cosines, and similarity. I got the answer $\frac{a}{a-1}$, but then I realized it was wrong because of a factoring issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle $\,ABC\,$ is similar to
$\,EDC.\,$ Use similarity of sides to get
$$ \frac{r_1}{a+r_1} = \frac{r_2}a = \sin(\alpha). \tag{1} $$
This implies
$$ 1-\sin(\alpha) = 1 - \frac{r_2}a = \frac{a-r_2}a. \tag{2} $$
Equality of ratios in equation $(1)$ gives us
$$ r_1\,a= (a+r_1)\,r_2 = a\,r_2 + r_1r_2. \tag{3} $$
Rearrange terms and and add $\,a^2\,$ to get
$$ a^2 = a^2 + r_1\,a - a\,r_2 - r_1r_2 = (a+r_1)(a-r_2). \tag{4} $$
This implies the equality of ratios
$$ \frac{a+r_1}a = \frac{a}{a-r_2}. \tag{5} $$
Combine equality of ratios in equation $(1)$ with equations $(2)$ and $(5)$ to get
$$ \frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{a+r_1}a= \frac{a}{a-r_2} = \frac1{1-\sin(\alpha)}. \tag{6} $$

Comment: Why does r1/r2  is equal to 1/1-sin(a)

Comment: @BilalErgüç I added more equations to derive $r_1/r_2=1/(1-\sin(\alpha))$.

Comment: Thank you so much 